# Jquery photo uploader with pintura - Edit photos after uploaded

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp, pintura

I have integrated the jquery file uploader to upload photos into my system with a pintura licence version.

Pintura edit button exists when adding images. and can edit images.
But there is no button to edit after uploaded the particular image.

If you can guide me through this it will be a great help to me.
(I need to edit images after upload as well using pintura.)

https://pqina.nl/pintura/
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

I installed jquery file uploader and integrated pintura. But can't see an edit button after uploaded the image.